# Show images from other folders with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, image

In first I have original images. And in the second folder I have thumbs with the same name. I want to show thumbs and link to original. How can I do it?

```
<html><?php 
      $folder = "img";
      $img_array = glob("$folder/*.*");

      arsort($img_array);
      if (!count($img_array)) { 
        echo"ERROR - no images in folder!"; die;  
      } 

    foreach($img_array as $key => $value) {    
    ?> 
            <a href="<?php echo $value; ?>"><img src="<?php SOMETHING THERE ?>" /></a>
    <?php } ?> 
</html>
```

Folder with original images: **img**

Folder with thumbs: **img/thumbs**

I want:

```
<a href="img/image1.jpg"><img src="img/thumbs/image1.jpg" /></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing your `img` folder is in the document root of your HTTP server:

```
<html>
<?php 
      $folder = "img";
      $img_array = glob("$folder/*.*");

      arsort($img_array);
      if (!count($img_array)) { 
          echo "ERROR - no images in folder!"; die;  
      } 

      foreach($img_array as $value) { 
          $name = basename($value);
          echo "<a href='/img/$name'><img src='/img/thumbs/$name' /></a>";
      } 
?> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the foreach, have an

```
<img src="img/" . "$imgName" />
```

and

```
<img src="img/thumbs/" . "$imgName" />
```

Then it will first show the image in the img folder, then the same image in the img/thumbs folder.

So the foreach will be something like this:

```
foreach($img_array as $key => $value) {    
    print("

        <a href='yourHTMLPage.html'><img src='img/' . '$value'></a>
        <a href='yourHTMLPage.html'><img src='img/thumbs/' . '$value'></a>

    ");
}
```

Comment: bad answer... in array i have whole path like: img/image1.jpg or img/image2.jpg ...

Comment: You could change the code, but I see the right answer already has been given.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I completely misunderstood it, but I think JeroenJKs answer doesn't fit.

You create a **link** with the `<a>`-Tag and instead of a text, you use your image.

```
<a href="<?php echo $value;?>"><img src="thumbs/<?php echo $value?>" /></a>
```

Seems almost too simple to me :o

Comment: try print $value and than you see that your answer is bad too

Comment: @Karol: I have no idea what you are trying to say. Why should printing $value be bad? You even did it in your code.

Comment: printing $value:
` img/image1.jpg`
` img/image2.jpg`
` img/image3.jpg`

Comment: and that's not what you want?

Comment: than you get:
<a href="img/img/image1.jpg"><img src="img/img/image1.jpg" /></a>
its bad i want <a href="img/image1.jpg"><img src="img/thumbs/image1.jpg" /></a>

Comment: Then just delete the img I made in both href and src. Did you even look into the code?

Comment: I'm not agree with your answer for many reasons. First, [is not remomended to use the short output tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use), and second and most important, the URLs are wrong because the [glob function](http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.glob.php) return the directory too.

Comment: I am a lazy bitch. But yes, you are right. Especially when I'm trying to explain something. Fixed it.